# find ASCII value of, 7 digit 1’s complement of a string(char) in java

Tags: char, twos-complement

I have to find ASCII value of 7 digit 1’s complement of a string(char) in java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You have a problem to start with, in that in Java, `char` is not interchangeable with `byte` -- for a reason. If you only have the ASCII charset to play with then that's fine; but otherwise...

Comment: That's too broad a question.  That C/C++ code shouldn't be confusing to you if you know java. It's almost identical to Java.

Comment: @1sand0s no it's not; as I said above, `char` and `byte` are not interchangeable for a good reason (character codings). In order to reproduce the algorithm, the OP needs to decode, manipulate the bytes, then re-encode again.

Comment: Using simple cast to int and cast back to char

Comment: Still, I fail to see, even reading the wikipedia's definition of one's completement, how you can obtain 0x41 from 0x3e... Maybe I'm short sighted or just plain idiot :/

Comment: @fge but that notwithstanding - the code is extremely similar to Java, and shouldn't be hard for him to understand. Finding a compatible data type for char is not a big leap.

Comment: @1sand0s First of all, I don't agree with "C/C++ code shouldn't be confusing to you if you know java" And second, I tried the same code in java, it doesn't work

Comment: @ShirishHerwade I didn't say *any* C/C++ code should be easy to understand, I mean your specific example is virtually identical to the equivalent Java code.  And I didn't say it was *exactly* identical or that you wouldn't have to port something from one language to the other, but it should be minimal.

Comment: Cast char to int, apply "the c++ logic", then cast it back... i though that apply the logic should be obvious...

Comment: Hmm, you should have avoided the last edit; the C code did show your intent to solve the problem... And now it has completely disappeared.

Comment: ha ha... i know, but first there is rare chance that this question is going to help someone and second, i don't want to reveal those things ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so let's start with the basics.

You need the one's complement *on 7 bits only* of the byte. Therefore it is true that, given 7 bytes only:

```
0x3E   =    0 011 1110
0x41   =    0 100 0001
```

0x41 is indeed the one's complement of 0x3E.

Now, you have a problem to begin with, and that problem is that in Java, a `char` is not interchangeable with a `byte` because of character codings.

However, since your range of characters is limited to ASCII, you can use US-ASCII as an encoding. So, the first step is to:

```
final Charset ascii = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;

final byte[] bytes = theInput.getBytes(ascii);

final byte[] transformedBytes = new byte[bytes.length];

byte original, transformed;

for (int index = 0; index < bytes.length; index++) {
    original = bytes[index];
    transformed = transformByte(original);
    transformedBytes[index] = transformed;
}

return new String(transformedBytes, ascii);
```

And now, the `transformedByte()` method needs to be written.

One's complement simply consists of a bitwise not on all the bytes, but here you want to limit that to 7 bytes; the solution is therefore to first do the negation normally, and then mask with 0x7f, which is `0111 1111`; this is made possible by the fact that none of your byte values have the highest bit set:

```
private static void transformByte(final byte original)
{
    return ~original & 0x7f;
}
```

This can be substituted directly into the original method, it's not even worth a separate method ;)

Comment: Why go to the trouble of converting chars to bytes and back again? Surely you can just transform chars using 7-bit 1's complement just the same way.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou because encoding; even though here this is ASCII only, this makes clear what the intent is (use US-ASCII etc). I've seen too much code written assuming ASCII using `char`s that I twitch every time I see such manipulations.

Comment: This looks like allocating memory for an extra (unnecessary) byte array just for code clarity and self-documentation. It may or may not be good use of resources (remember, this is on a potentially memory-constrained Android system) depending on exact use. Personally, I would just use a comment.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou well, that would be your choice, not mine ;) And Android systems are generally not _that_ constrained to care about that -- unless your strings are huge.

Comment: @fge thanks bro, but having 1 issue, getting exception NoClassDefErrror for StandardCharsets, seems it available from API level 19 only. Is there any work arround?

Comment: @ShirishHerwade it works "by chance", in that the default encoding of your platform seems to have a 1-1 char-byte compatibility with your data. Otherwise you can always use `Charset.forName("US-ASCII")` instead.